# FFmpeg complex filter Invalid stream specifier: v2

Tags: ffmpeg, ffprobe

I am new in ffmpeg, When i am trying the below ffmpeg command i got the `Invalid stream specifier: v2` . What was the reason for this error?

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex " \
[0:v]crop=100:100:50:50,boxblur=10:enable='between(t,0,5)'[v1]; \
[0:v][v1]overlay=50:50[v2]; \
[v2]crop=200:200:400:400,boxblur=10:enable='between(t,5,12)'[v3]; \
[v2][v3]overlay=400:400[v4]; \
[v4]crop=640:360:0:0,scale=-1:720[v5]; \
[v4][v5]overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,0,5)'[output]" \
-map "[output]" \
output-mixed-100.mp4
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add split

```
ffmpeg -i "input 1.mp4" -filter_complex "
[0:v]crop=100:100:50:50,boxblur=10:enable='between(t,0,5)'[v1];
[0:v][v1]overlay=50:50,split[v2][v3];
[v3]crop=200:200:400:400,boxblur=10:enable='between(t,5,12)'[v3];
[v2][v3]overlay=400:400,split[v4][v5];
[v5]crop=640:360:0:0,scale=-1:720[v5];
[v4][v5]overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,0,5)'
" out.mp4
```

Comment: Thank you , Its working as i expected.